# How to set pressed=false for mouse area QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I've faced with next situation:

I have an Item with MouseArea. This is my button on the screen - keyboard.

1. I persorm long press for button on keyboard.
2. I don't release this button (holding it).
3. In onPressed{} signal handler I'm opening another screen.
4. My buton from keyboard doesn't receive anymore Release signal.
5. When I come back to the previous keyboard - my button still pressed.

I've tried to set "pressed"=false, but this is readonly property.

I've tried to emit released() signal, but it doesn't clear the "pressed' flag.
But I think that I did it in wrong way. Function release takes parameter- mause - mouseEvent. The mouse parameter provides information about the click, including the x and y position of the release of the click, and whether the click was held. And I didn't find how to set it correct.

I've tried to update MouseArea, it doesn't help.

I don't know what else I have to try to unsed the "pressed" flag.

My mouse area is simple:

```
MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea

    property bool haveToRelease: false

    onHaveToReleaseChanged: {
        if(haveToRelease)
        {
            console.log("BaseButton.qml: call canceled()")
            released()
            haveToRelease = false
        }
    }

    anchors.fill: parent
    hoverEnabled: true

    onReleased: {
        console.log("BaseButton.qml: onReleased")
    }

    onPressedChanged: {
        console.log("BaseButton.qml: onPressedChanged, pressed = ", pressed)
    }
}
```

In my button I have the next handler:

```
onVisibleChanged: {
    if(config.isToyota && !visible && pressed) {
        console.log("Key.qml :: config.isToyota && !visible && pressed")
        releaseButton = true
    }
}
```

I will be vary glad if somebody help me to solve this issue!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't follow your code. Could you make it a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? So including the `onPressed` and all other necessary stuff, to run it, and see your problem. Because as @folibis showed, it works. So the error must happen someplace else.

Answer (score 1):

as for me that works as expected:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "orange"
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                console.log("pressed");
                wnd.show();
                released(mouse);
            }
            onReleased: {
                console.log("released");
            }
            onPressedChanged: console.log("pressed: " + pressed );
        }
    }

    Window {
        id: wnd
        width: 200
        height: 200
    }
}
```

The output:

```
qml: pressed
qml: released
qml: pressed: true
qml: pressed: false
```